# I have a column of dates, how to filter dates before a specific day? R

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my data

```
print(data)
     mydates
1   9/17/2019
2   3/8/2020
3   9/20/2020
4   7/19/2020
5   10/22/2020
6   9/12/2020
```

I want to filter so I only see dates in September, but it is not working.

This is my code

````
data$mydates <- as.Date(data$mydates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

Septdata <- data %>% filter(mydates < '2020-01-09')

```

Is this correct?
````

Comment: Try `Septdata <- data %>% filter(mydates < as.Date('2020-09-01'))`

Comment: In fact, `data %>% filter(mydates < '2020-09-01')` would also work if you specify the date correctly in the Y-M-D pattern. This keeps the selected dates instead of filtering them out however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

df <- setDT(your_dataset)

df_sep <- df[mydates >= as.Date('2020-09-01') & mydates <= as.Date('2020-09-30')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you want to filter between two dates is using dplyr package:

```
data%>% filter(mydate >= as.Date("2020-09-01") & mydate <= as.Date("2020-01-09"))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `base R` using `subset`

```
subset(data, mydate >= as.Date("2020-09-01") & mydate <= as.Date("2020-01-09"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `mydate` to date class and filter for specific months and/or year

If you want all the dates in 'Septempber' :

```
data$mydates <- as.Date(data$mydates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
subset(data, as.integer(format(mydates, '%m')) == 9)

#     mydates
#1 2019-09-17
#2 2020-09-20
#3 2020-09-12
```

If you want all the dates in September of 2020

```
subset(data, as.integer(format(mydates, '%m')) == 9 & 
             as.integer(format(mydates, '%Y')) == 2020)

#     mydates
#1 2020-09-20
#2 2020-09-12
```

---

You can implement the same logic with `dplyr` + `lubridate` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
  mutate(mydates = mdy(mydates)) %>%
  filter(month(mydates) == 9)


data %>%
  mutate(mydates = mdy(mydates)) %>%
  filter(month(mydates) == 9 & year(mydates) == 2020)
```